# GROUP_CONCAT not working with IN() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-concat

I need to return values using the **IN()** statement based on the values of a **GROUP_CONCAT()** statement.

This query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(ID)) FROM primary_batch
```

rightfully returns

```
'4','2','6','3','5','1'
```

However this query

```
SELECT * FROM secondary_batch WHERE id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(ID)) FROM primary_batch)
```

does not return any output

However if I place the actual values

```
SELECT * FROM secondary_batch WHERE id IN ('4','2','6','3','5','1')
```

I get the output I expect.

I cannot figure out why this is happening. I am using MySQL v5.7.

I am open to using other solutions based on stored procedures to achieve this result if indeed there is a limitation to using **GROUP_CONCAT/IN** statements in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However if I place the actual values
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM secondary_batch WHERE id IN ('4','2','6','3','5','1')
> ```
>
> I get the output I expect.

That's not right. Really your query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM secondary_batch WHERE id IN ('\'4\',\'2\',\'6\',\'3\',\'5\',\'1\'')
```

i.e. is not a list, it is a value of one string literal.

If you want to use GROUP_CONCAT() in subquery certainly then you must use

```
SELECT * 
FROM secondary_batch 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(ID)) FROM primary_batch))
```

But it is excess, illogical and makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks @Akina your statement ```i.e. is not a list, it is a value of one string literal.``` led me to look for another solution.

Comment: (The `FIND_IN_SET` approach will be slow; no index can be used.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not appropriate to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in the subquery, as you want to return individual `ID` values, not a string of comma separated ones (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) for a discussion on how to use `IN` with subqueries). This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM secondary_batch
WHERE id IN (SELECT ID FROM primary_batch)
```